# File Upload not binding file to view if there is any modelvalidation errors in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

hi am facing problem with file upload control ..am validating my code on server side ..in one of the view am using file upload control to upload file ..if there is any model validation occurred am returning same view with data but file upload control is empty ..what will be the exact solution to this and am using httppostedfilebase property to store files please help me and your help would be greatly  appreciated

```
public class EmployeeDocumentsTable
        {
         public string EmployeeDocumentName { get; set; }
                public string EmployeeDocumentDescription { get; set; }
                [Required]
               // [RegularExpression(@"^.*\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG|pdf|PDF)$", ErrorMessage = "Please use an image with an extension of .jpg, .png, .pdf")]
                public HttpPostedFileBase EmployeeDocumentFileName { get; set; }

am binding HttpPostedFileBase in view Like is 

     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DocumentDetailsFields.documentsList[i].EmployeeDocumentFileName, new { type = "file" })
```

i created list for EmployeeDocumentsTable as shown documentsList is a list

Comment: post your model class code

Comment: Here I need to Bind the uploaded file again to view if there is any validation errors

Comment: try this                                             @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DocumentDetailsFields.documentsList[i].EmployeeDocumentFileName, new { type = "file" }, Value=Model.DocumentDetailsFields.documentsList[i].EmployeeDocumentFileName.HasValue ? Model.DocumentDetailsFields.documentsList[i].EmployeeDocumentFileName :"")

Comment: Giving Syntax error ;;after  new { type = "file" } Value=Model.DocumentDetailsFields.documentsList[i].EmployeeDocumentFileName.HasV‌​alue ? Model.DocumentDetailsFields.documentsList[i].EmployeeDocumentFileName :""})

Comment: Where to define value within html attribute or what give me the clear picture

Comment: Has Value giving Error.visual studio not showing Hasvalue after EmployeeDocumentFileName.

Comment: USE THIS  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DocumentDetailsFields.documentsList[i].EmployeeDocumentFileName, new { type = "file" , Value=Model.DocumentDetailsFields.documentsList[i].EmployeeDocumentFileName.HasValue ? Model.DocumentDetailsFields.documentsList[i].EmployeeDocumentFileName :""})

Comment: Hasvalue not fit for EmployeeDocumentFileName giving error

Comment: EmployeeDocumentFileName.Value==null or Value==""

Comment: Sorry No use With value its httppostedfilebase please cross check once its very important

Comment: just type model.DocumentDetailsFields.documentsList[i].EmployeeDocumentFileName == null  and check.